Dissect the given shape into 4 congruent pieces each containing 2 circles and 1 square
Warmup question:
Dissect the shape shown below into 4 congruent pieces each containing 2 circles and 1 square.

Clarifications:
The 4 pieces can be rotated and/or reflected versions of each other.
The 4 pieces don’t necessarily have to each contain the same amount of black border from the original shape.

Challenge question:
Are there solutions to the above problem where the edges of the pieces cut through the circles and/or squares?
If so, the amount of circular bits must total 2 full circles for each of the 4 pieces AND the amount of square bits must total 1 full square for each of the 4 pieces.

Attributions:
Warmup question:  The Moscow Puzzles by BORIS A. KORDEMSKY.
Challenge question:  Me

Solution for the warm up:

 

Solution for the challenge:

 


I count 8 shapes?

+1 Cool solution to challenge question!

Well if this is allowed that’s a poorly worded question

@PDT I didn’t say the 4 pieces had to be connected.  Calling my question poorly worded is not nice.

All I mean is that it should have been specified please don’t take it personally
